# Compare True Contribution with SHAP Contribution, using simulated data

Tags: explainable-ai

I try to compare the true contribution with SHAP Contribution, using simulated data. Because the data is simulated, I have the ground truth contribution of each variable for each observation, which I expected SHAP to give similar contribution. But results are quite different, and I am trying to understand why. Please see details below:

1. Simulate X: generate 4 random variables (x1,x2,x3 and x4).See code section A.
2. Similate Y: Let log_odds = x1+x2+x3+x4 (setting all coefficient to 1 and intercept to 0). Then convert log_odds to probability, and use probability to generate binary outcome. Since coefficients are 1 and intercept is 0, the x value is the contribution to the log_odds of the observation. See code section B.
3. Fit logistic regression. The estimated coefficients are very close to ones used for simulation. The AUC is 0.92. coef: [0.98761674 1.00301607 1.01310563 0.98102926] Intercept [0.03131222]. See code section C.
4. Get KernelSHAP, and put it side by side with the x table ( the true contribution). See code section D.

The intercept in data generation is 0, and the bias term for SHAP (explainer.expected_value[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJKd1.jpg)) is -0.003, which is also close to 0. Thus, I guess I can compare x value with SHAP value for each variable. Please see results for 10 observations below:

1. The x value and SHAP value are not quite comparable;
2. For each observation, the contribution rank order within 4 variables (x1,x2,x3,x,4) is not consistent with the rank order in the SHAP value.
3. In data generation, x1 and x2 are all positive numbers, while x3 and x4 are all negative numbers. Thus in SHAP columns, I would expect to see some pattern, however, the pattern in SHAP columns are quite random.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is there any flaw in my testing design, such that the comparison between x value and SHAP value is totally irrelevant?
2. Is this the SHAP results I should expect?
3. Why SHAP gives contribution that deviate so much for the actual value and rank order?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder, MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shap
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy.random import randint

##Section A: Simulate X
random_n=2
random.seed(random_n)
seed(random_n)
n=10000
x1=np.array(rand(n))*5 # The larger the *n, the further log_odds is pushed away from 0, the easier data to model.
x2=np.array(rand(n))*5
x3=-np.array(rand(n))*5
x4=-np.array(rand(n))*5
df=pd.DataFrame({"x1":x1,"x2":x2,"x3":x3,"x4":x4})

## Section B: Simulate Y
def logistic(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
lp=x1+x2+x3+x4
prob = logistic(lp)
y = np.random.binomial(1, prob.flatten())
print("mean of y: ", np.mean(y))
print("log_odds of mean: ",np.log(np.mean(y)/(1-(np.mean(y)))))

## Section C: Fit logistic regression and make sure AUC is reasonable
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
LR = LogisticRegression(penalty='none')
LR.fit(df.values,y)
print("coef:      ",LR.coef_, LR.intercept_)
print("AUC:       ",roc_auc_score(y, LR.predict_proba(df)[:,1]))

## Section D: Get KernelSHAP, and compare with tree contribution (for k observations)
k=10
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(LR.predict_proba, df, feature_perturbation="interventional", nsamples=10000, link="logit")
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df[0:k])

df_shap=pd.DataFrame(shap_values[1],columns=("SHAP_x1","SHAP_x2","SHAP_x3","SHAP_x4"))
df_shap_L=pd.concat([df.iloc[0:k,:], df_shap], axis=1)
df_shap_L['log_odd_true']=np.log(prob/(1-prob))[0:k]
prob_pred =LR.predict_proba(df)[:,1][0:k] 
df_shap_L['log_odd_pred']=np.log(prob_pred/(1-prob_pred))[0:k]
```